# Why drawing trees/nature allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, image, drawing

I know it's not allowed drawing human/animal.But I found no scholar saying drawing trees are not allowed.So why drawing trees are allowed?

Comment: I read it.Thanks.Okay,so,it's because of soul,right?